# loadUrl error "ERR_ABORTED (-3) error" can't be catched

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an page that is behind an Auth0 login. When you have the proper session, you are automatically redirected to a final page.

The problem is I am doing this using `loadURL` on Electron and the `loadURL` [throw a `Uncaught (in promise) Error: ERR_ABORTED (-3)`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/c41b8d536b2d886abbe739374c0a46f99242a894/lib/browser/navigation-controller.ts#L77-L86).

I would like to rescue this error, because visually everything is working well on my app and I do not see a way to fix this error.

But I am not able to rescue with [`did-load-fail`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-fail-load). Here is a code snippet I have on my app.

```js
  const { remote } = require('electron');
  const win = new remote.BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      partition: LOGIN_PARTITION,
      nodeIntegration: false,
    },
  });
  win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    console.log('finish-load'); // triggered twice
  });
  win.webContents.on('did-fail-load', () => {
    console.log('fail-load'); // never triggered
  });
  try {
    win.loadURL(urlThatContainsAutoRedirect);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('catch loadUrl'); // never triggered
  }
  win.show();
```

How could I avoid this error or rescue it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadUrl` returns Promise (https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/c41b8d536b2d886abbe739374c0a46f99242a894/lib/browser/navigation-controller.ts#L53) that you can't catch via synchronous try/catch. either use catch handler in `then` or use `.catch`. Also note it may not work in remote proxied renderer process, in that case it need to be handled in main process.

Comment: You are correct. I ended up doing 
```
win.loadURL(url).catch((error: any) => {
    if (error.code === 'ERR_ABORTED') return;
    throw error;
  });
```